# Formatting time on a time series matplotlib plot

Tags: matplotlib

I am plotting temperature in a dynamic, ie. ever increasing, time series plot using matplotlib.

My xaxis is:

```
g_my_globals.t_array.append(datetime.datetime.now())
g_my_globals.y_array.append(fahrMash) #temperature from a sensor
g_my_globals.axis.plot(t_array,y_array)
```

Without any further statements, the plot I generate shows (horizontally) hh:mm:ss. If I rotate the xlabels:

```
g_my_globals.axis.set_xticklabels(t_array,rotation="vertical")
```

I see the entire time structure, ie. MM/DD/YYY HH:MM:SS, squishing the actual plot. All my attempts to format the xticklabels to be just '$H:%M:%S' have failed. Reaching out, hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: See this [reference](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks/date_demo_convert.html#sphx-glr-gallery-ticks-date-demo-convert-py)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have been reading the documentation. My problem seems to be that g_my_globals does not have an attribute 'xaxis'

Maybe because the plot is a subplot to the larger window/frame? In the "working" version, ie. where time is written out as full date and time to fraction of second, I also get a warning that one of the axis is not compatible with tight_layout.

All this code was adapted from examples I found years ago.